# Growing rate of f(n) = $10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 10$ with n 10's

Tags: nt.number-theory, growth-rate

I would like to have an estimate for a really fast growing function and a number.

Define the following function

f(n) = $10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow ... \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 10$

with n 10's.

The rules for the conway-chains are as follows

- A chain with a single number p simply has value p.
- $p\rightarrow q = p^q$
- $p\rightarrow q \rightarrow  r = p \uparrow^r q$
- $X \rightarrow (p+1) \rightarrow (q+1) = X \rightarrow (X \rightarrow p \rightarrow(q+1)) \rightarrow q$ for any chain X and any numbers $p,q\ge1$
- $X \rightarrow 1 \rightarrow Y = X$ for any chains X,Y
- $2 \rightarrow 2 \rightarrow X = 4$ for any chain X

f(n) is growing really quickly

f(1) = 10

f(2) = $10^{10}$

f(3) = $10 \uparrow^{10} 10$

f(4) = $10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 10 \rightarrow 10$

f(4) is already much much larger than graham's number.

What growing rate does this function approximately have ? At which position in the
fast growing hierachy is it ?

Now, define the following sequence

$g_1 = 10$

$g_{n+1} = f({g_n})$ for all $n\ge1$

So, $g_2$ is a conway chain containing 10 tens, $g_3$ is a conway chain containing $g_2$
tens and so on.

The number, I am interested in is

N = $\large g_{g_2}$

Is $\large f_{\epsilon_0}(3)$ already larger than N, or perhaps already
$\large f_{\omega^\omega}(3)$ ? How can I estimate the magnitude of N ?

Comment: Tends to $0$ for $2-$ and $5-$adic valuations.

Comment: According to http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Chained_arrow_notation your function $f$ is comparable to $f_{\omega^2}$.  We can conclude that $g_n$ is comparable to $f_{\omega^2+1}(n)$.  $g_{g_2}$ is much smaller than $f_{\omega^\omega}(3)$.

Comment: Very nice answer!